# Given probabilities of a horse beating each other horse. What is the probability that the horse will finish in a particular position?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have computed probabilities that horse A beats horse B, horse A beats horse C and so on.
I want to find out the probability that the horse will finish in a particular position, say 2nd.

Edit:
In a horse race, with multiple horses. I know the probability that horse 1 will be horse 2 and probability that horse 1 will beat horse 3 and so on.
eg:
probability of horse 1 beating horse 2 depicted as h1->h2: P
h1->h2: 0.6
h1->h3: 0.7
h1->h4: 0.75
h1->h5: 0.8

i want to know what is the probability that horse 1 will attain a position say 2nd or 3rd?

Comment: @2000 I believe OP is talking about horse racing.

Comment: This needs clarification:  do you mean that you know the probability that, say, A will beat B in a two horse race or do you mean you know the probability that in the tournament in question you know the probability that A will come out ahead of B?  (since the two horse competitions are not independent events I don't believe the two types of data are equivalent).

Comment: Related (but a little less general): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878910/calculating-probabilities-in-horse-racing

Comment: @Micah  Good reference.  In particular, if you treat each pairwise horse race as a fair coin toss then it is not necessarily true that each horse has an equal chance of winning a group race.  Somewhat unintuitive.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness:  I think the problem is ill-posed as written, because knowing the probabilities that horse #i beats horse #j in a 1:1 match up does not tell you the odds of any particular horse winning a group race.  To see this, let's just take a three horse race and to keep it simple let's assume that the outcome between any two horse is 50:50.  We'll construct an example in which A is more likely to win the race than B.

Construction:  model the race by saying that the outcome will be a weighted draw of the possible outcomes.  Specifically let $$p_1 = Prob(A,B,C)$$
$$p_2 =Prob(B,C,A)$$
$$p_3=Prob(C,A,B)$$
$$p_4 = Prob(A,C,B)$$
$$p_5 = Prob(B,A,C)$$
$$p_6= Prob(C,B,A)$$
What do we know?  Well of course these 6 numbers must add to 1.  Better than that, we know these numbers must be consistent with the assumed probabilities of the two horse competitions.  Thus, for example, we know that $$\frac{1}{2} = Prob(A,B)=p_1+p_3+p_4$$
Since those three cases are the only three in which A beats B.
Similarly $$p_1+p_2+p_5 = Prob(B,C) = \frac{1}{2} = Prob(A,C) = p_1+p_4+p_5$$
Thus we have 3 equations in 5 unknowns.  There are infinitely many solutions.  For example, it is easy to verify that taking {$p_i$} = {.3, .1, .1, .1, .1, .3} works.  Let's take this particular example to be our probabilities.  In this case, the probability that A wins the three horse contest is $p_1+p_4=\frac{4}{10}$ (this is also the probability that C wins.  The probability that B wins is $\frac{2}{10}$).

Answer (score 0):

If there are
$n$ horses,
$h_i, i=1, ..., n$,
and you know
$p_{ij}$,
the probability that
horse $i$ beats horse $j$,
I would argue like this:

First of all,
I assume that there is
zero probability of
a tie,
so $p_{ij}+p_{ji} = 1$.

For any permutation
$\pi$
of
$[1, ..., n]$,
I would define the probability
of that permutation occurring
is
$\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} \prod_{j=i+1}^n p_{\pi(i)\pi(j)}
=\prod_{j=2}^{n} \prod_{i=1}^{j-1} p_{\pi(i)\pi(j)}
=\prod_{1\le i < j \le n} p_{\pi(i)\pi(j)}
$.
This is because,
for that permutation to happen,
horse $\pi(i)$
has to beat
horse $\pi(j)$
for all combinations of $j > i
$.

I think it would be possible
to prove
(by induction)
that the sum of this probability
of all permutations
is $1$.
(Oops.
Further on
I show that this does
*not* hold
for $n=3$.)

For $n=2$,
the permutations are
$[1, 2]$ and $[2, 1]$.
The probability of
$[1, 2]$
is
$p_{12}
$
and
the probability of
$[2, 1]$
is
$p_{21}
$
and the sum of these is $1$.

For $n=3$,
the permutations are
$[123], [132], [213], [231], [312], [321]$.
The probabilities are

$\begin{array}\\
123& p_{12}p_{13}p_{23}\\
132& p_{13}p_{12}p_{32}\\
213& p_{21}p_{23}p_{13}\\
231& p_{23}p_{21}p_{31}\\
312& p_{31}p_{32}p_{12}\\
321& p_{32}p_{31}p_{21}\\
\end{array}
$

and the sum of these is

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{\pi([123])} \prod_{1\le i < j \le 3} p_{\pi(i)\pi(j)}
&=p_{12}p_{13}p_{23}+p_{13}p_{12}p_{32}
+ p_{21}p_{23}p_{13}+  p_{23}p_{21}p_{31}
+ p_{31}p_{32}p_{12}+ p_{32}p_{31}p_{21}\\
&=p_{12}p_{13}p_{23}+p_{13}p_{12}(1-p_{23})
+ p_{21}p_{23}p_{13}+  p_{23}p_{21}(1-p_{13})
+ p_{31}p_{32}p_{12}+ p_{32}p_{31}(1-p_{12})\\
&=p_{12}p_{13}
+ p_{21}p_{23}
+ p_{31}p_{32}\\
&=p_{12}p_{13}
+ (1-p_{12})p_{23}
+ (1-p_{13})(1-p_{23})\\
&=p_{12}p_{13}
+ p_{23}-p_{23}p_{12}
+ 1-p_{13}-p_{23}+p_{13}p_{23}\\
&=1+p_{12}p_{13}
-p_{23}p_{12}
+ p_{13}+p_{13}p_{23}\\
\end{array}
$

Interesting.
Unless I made a mistake
(which is not unlikely),
the sum is not $1$
unless
$p_{12}p_{13}
-p_{23}p_{12}
+ p_{13}+p_{13}p_{23}
= 0
$
or
$p_{23}p_{12}
=p_{12}p_{13}
+ p_{13}+p_{13}p_{23}
=p_{13}(1+p_{12}+p_{23})
$.

I don't know whether
this is a
genuine consistency condition
or a result of an error of mine.

Oh well.
We can always divide each probability
by their sum,
making it into
a genuine probability.