# Probability of top $3$ Horses ranked in a certain order

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, gambling

Lets say I have a bunch of horses in a race, and I know that probabilities of them winning are:

- $P(A) = 0.4$
- $P(B) = 0.3$
- $P(C) = 0.2$
- $P(D) = 0.08$
- $P(E) = 0.02$

**QUESTION 1:** How would I go about calculating the probability that the top 3 horses turn out to be arranged in this order:

1. Horse $B$
2. Horse $A$
3. Horse $C$

**QUESTION 2:** How would I go about calculating the probability that Horses $A$, $B$, and $C$ are all in the top $3$, irrespective of order?

**SIMILAR POSTS**

I have tried searching for similar posts, but haven't found one that gives me a clear idea about how to answer my specific question.

- [How to find top 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2565031/how-to-find-top-3)
- [Calculating probabilities in horse racing!](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878910/calculating-probabilities-in-horse-racing)
- [Given every horse's chance of winning a race, what is the probability that a specific horse will finish in nth place?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/625611/given-every-horses-chance-of-winning-a-race-what-is-the-probability-that-a-spe)

Comment: My answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/625611/given-every-horses-chance-of-winning-a-race-what-is-the-probability-that-a-spe/4247021#4247021 addresses your question directly and in reasonable generality (arbitrary performance distributions). The answers below assume Luce' Axiom of choice without realizing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that although you have given us the probability that each horse, we can't deduce the probability of a particular ranking without making further assumptions.

Here is a reasonable set of assumptions: let $S$ denote a subset $S \subset \{A,\dots,E\}$. Let $i$ denote an element of $S$. I assume that

- The probability that $i$ comes first in a race among the elements of $S$ is
  $$
  P = \frac{P(i)}{\sum_{j \in S} P(j)} = \frac{P(i)}{1 - \sum_{j \notin S} P(j)}.
  $$
  That is, it is equal to the probability that $i$ comes first in a race of all horses given that the horses not in the race do not come first.
- The probability of a ranking in which $i$ comes first is equal to the above probability multiplied by the overall probability of the ranking of $S \setminus \{i\}$. That is, the presence of the top horse does not affect the relative ranking of the remaining horses.

With these assumptions, we find that the overall probability of the order $B,A,C$ (the answer to question 1) is given by
$$
P = P(B) \cdot \frac{P(A)}{1 - P(B)} \cdot \frac{P(C)}{1 - P(A) - P(B)} \approx 11.4 \%.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much :)  I appreciate that you provided the general formula for how to calculate it.

Answer (score 1):

Probability of B winning the race $= 0.3$

Now to find the probability of $A$ finishing 2nd given $B$ wins the race, you have to calculate the odd of $A$ winning against remaining horses

$= \dfrac{0.4}{0.7}$

Now to find the probability of $C$ finishing 3rd given $A$ and $B$ have finished in top 2, you have to calculate the odds of $C$ winning against remaining horses

$= \dfrac{0.2}{0.3}$

So Probability of $B A C$ being ranked $1, 2, 3 = \dfrac{0.3 \times 0.4 \times 0.2}{0.7 \times 0.3} = \dfrac{4}{35}$

This is obviously based on assumption that probabilities of winning the race can be extended.

Comment: You can do the second question similarly

Comment: Thank you very much